# divs are horizontally displayed in Firefox but are (incorrectly) vertically stacked in IE9

Tags: html, firefox, internet-explorer-9, css

In Firefox version 10, 11 the following divs appear as I want -- left-to-right, horizontally:

```
   .containerForListStyles
   {
       width: 100%;
       margin: 0 auto;
       display:inline-block;
   }

   .listStyle1
   {
       font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
       display:inline-block;
       width: 250px;
       margin-right: 5px;
       margin-left: 3%;
   }

  .listStyle2
  {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      display:inline-block;
      width: 250px;
      margin-left: 5px;
      margin-right: 3%;
  }

     <div class="containerForListStyles">
       <a href="www.oursite.com"><img src="www.oursite.com/images/logo-landing2.png"</img></a>
       <div class="listStyle1">  
               This is the center div's text
       </div>
       <div class="listStyle2">     
               This is the right side text...
       </div>
    </div>
```

In Firefox the image is on the left, then the listStyle1 div is to its right, then the listStyle2 div is to the right of that, all on the same line.

In IE9 the 3 elements (image anchor, div 1 and div 2) are stacked *vertically.*

So I studied some SO posts about inline-block and IE troubles but the posts all said 'pre-IE8' or 'pre-IE7' there were problems.

What do I need to change so that IE9 shows the horizontal left/middle/right layout of these 3 divs?
It seems like IE9 ignores 'inline-block'.

NOTE:  My Android smartphone (HTC Evo) correctly shows the same desired horizontal layout that Firefox does.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try floating the elements?

Comment: We're not switching from inline-block.  We are pretty sure that's not the problem -- there are no complaints about inline-block and IE9.  The fact is the UI is fine in the other browsers -- only IE9 vertically stacks the divs.   Gotta be something we're doing wrong that is 'overlooked' in the other browsers or something we're doing is okay but is being 'underlooked' in IE9.

Comment: Are you setting a hard width for the body tag?  Is there a place we can view the entire source?  There could be something happening higher up in the stack.

Comment: Your intuition was correct.  All throughout our code we had the following syntax:  ***require_once 'somefile.php'***  and we noticed that all the code samples we found as we tried to solve this used a completely different syntax -- of the form ***require_once('somefile.php')*** and after that change, IE9 now 100% honors the inline-block.